# List of IP addresses in Python to a list of CIDR

Tags: python, ip, cidr

How do I convert a list of IP addresses to a list of CIDRs?  [Google's ipaddr-py library](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) has a method called summarize_address_range(first, last) that converts two IP addresses (start & finish) to a CIDR list.  However, it cannot handle a list of IP addresses.

```
Example:
>>> list_of_ips = ['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5']
>>> convert_to_cidr(list_of_ips)
['10.0.0.0/30','10.0.0.5/32']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in python3, we have a buildin module for this: ipaddress.

```
list_of_ips = ['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5']
import ipaddress
nets = [ipaddress.ip_network(_ip) for _ip in list_of_ips]
cidrs = ipaddress.collapse_addresses(nets)
list(cidrs)
Out[6]: [IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/30'), IPv4Network('10.0.0.5/32')]
```

Answer (score 6):

Install netaddr.

> > > pip install netaddr

Use functions of netaddr:

```
# Generate lists of IP addresses in range.
ip_range = netaddr.iter_iprange(ip_start, ip_end)
# Convert start & finish range to CIDR.
ip_range = netaddr.cidr_merge(ip_range)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line using netaddr:

```py
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(ip_start, ip_end)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, `summarize_address_range` reduces your problem to splitting your list into consecutive ranges. Given that you can convert IP addresses to integers using

```
def to_int(str): struct.unpack("!i",socket.inet_aton(str))[0]
```

this should not be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

For the comment made by CaTalyst.X, note that you need to change to code in order for it to work.

This:

```
cidrs = netaddr.ip_range_to_cidrs('54.64.0.0', '54.71.255.255')
```

Needs to become this:

```
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs('54.64.0.0', '54.71.255.255')
```

If you use the first instance of the code, you'll get an exception since ip_range_to_cidrs isn't a valid attribute to the netaddr method.

Answer (score 0):

Expand CIDR ranges into full IP lists, by taking an input file of ranges and utilizing netaddr
https://github.com/JeremyNGalloway/cidrExpand/blob/master/cidrExpand.py

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'example usage: python cidrExpand.py cidrRanges.txt >> output.txt'

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as cidrRanges:
    for line in cidrRanges:
        ip = IPNetwork(line)
        for ip in ip:
            print ip

cidrRanges.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

5 minutes solution

- Copy the list in Excel column
- go to "Data->Text to Columns" and split with delimiter "."
- In case you want the "/24" ranges, concatenate first 3 columns with the following formula
  =A1&"."&B1&"."&C1&".0/24".
- Copy the new column and paste "Values only" in another column.
- Remove duplicates of this column from "Data->Remove Duplicates"
- Your "/24" cider list is ready. You can make "/16" and "/8" same way.

Thank me later :-P

Comment: Hi, this doesn't actually answer the constraints of OP's question since they explicitly asked for Python solutions.