# summarize very long list of ipv4 addresses in python

Tags: python, network-programming, ip, summarization

I have a very long list of IPv4 addresses (~18k) that i would like to summarize as much as possible: eg

```
119.195.74.210
119.196.154.2
119.196.247.223
119.197.20.186
119.199.160.107
119.199.160.32
119.199.160.33
119.199.160.34
119.199.160.54
119.199.160.55
```

should end up something like

```
119.195.74.210/32
119.196.154.2/32
119.196.247.223/32
119.197.20.186/32
119.199.160.107/32
119.199.160.32/31
119.199.160.34/32
119.199.160.54/31
```

speed is important.

any suggestions?

Comment: is there any patter for appending /32 and /31

Comment: These address spaces doesn't add up very well.. Are you sure they're valid address spaces? Because it looks like you've just randomly put /31 on one spot and then /32.. Logic goes against this when having `.32` in a 31 subnet, and `.34` in a 32 subnet, but then suddenly `.54` in a 31 subnet again.. It doesn't look like a good structure to me :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708272/list-of-ip-addresses-in-python-to-a-list-of-cidr

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `netaddr` module. Assuming that you have a text file with the IP addresses, your code could look something like this:

```
import sys
from netaddr import IPAddress, cidr_merge

fh     = open (sys.argv[1], 'r')
iplist = list()
for addr in fh:
    addr = IPAddress (addr.strip())
    iplist.append (addr)

fh.close()
print cidr_merge (iplist)
```