# Advice converting single IP lists to CIDR format

Tags: ip, cidr

I'm trying to convert the IP lists from here:

http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/bots

into CIDR format.

As you can see, the current format is similar to:

```
131.253.46.102  msnbot-131-253-46-102.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.105  msnbot-131-253-46-105.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.108  msnbot-131-253-46-108.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.112  msnbot-131-253-46-112.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.114  msnbot-131-253-46-114.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.116  msnbot-131-253-46-116.search.msn.com    US
131.253.46.120  msnbot-131-253-46-120.search.msn.com    US
etc.
```

I have found a script on github here:

https://github.com/NewEraCracker/php_work/blob/master/ipRangeCalculate.php

Which I THINK does what I want, but I'm unsure how to use it to get the results I want.

Will this script achieve what I want it to, and if so, how best to use it.  If not, is there a solution I haven't found yet?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of IP addresses in Python to a list of CIDR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708272/list-of-ip-addresses-in-python-to-a-list-of-cidr)

Comment: Thanks, I found that before posting but given the difference in source list layout I wasn't sure how to proceed with it or if in fact it would have done what I wanted.

If it can be used to do what I need please do tell me how, thanks.